# python - obfuscating distributed text/image/sound files

Tags: python, obfuscation

In distributing my app, I'd like to prevent casual users from viewing my png files, playing my mp3s or reading/modifying the plain text files I use to load and store data. The text I guess could be binary pickled? What about the images/sounds? What do you do when distributing your app?

Assuming py2exe or py2app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip files, but they'll be visible while the program is running; you could extract them to a run-time generated temporary directory with `tempfile.mkdtemp()`, but it still would not be difficult to track them down.

Another solution would be to use a light-weight encryption, or even simple obfuscation (such as [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) for the text files, and a simple [xor cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) on the binary files).  This will add some time to the execution of your program, so make sure and take that into account.

Comment: Well points to anyone that wants to describe ROT13 or xor using python as I can't seem to google out how to do it.

Comment: @Mark, sounds like a new question!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could archive those files and at runtime unarchive, use, then delete them:

[Here is an article regarding Work with ZIP archives](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html)

Not a very strong protection method, but it will discourage hobby hackers